# Burst Time same as Required time Operating Systems

Tags: time, process, system

I have this table :

```
Process     Time of arrival     Required time   Priority
--------    ---------------     -------------   --------
P1          6                   4               5

P2          2                   9               2

P3          4                   6               1

P4          10                  4               30
```

SJF, SRTF, and Priority (Preemptive and non preemptive)

In the examples I see Burst time used , what is equivalent of that word should I use required time ?